# How to make two elements always stay at the same height?

Tags: html, css

I have two

one is an image one a piece of text. I need the bottom of the text to align with the bottom of the text at a relative scale. I can make them both align with margin-top but not when I change the window size. [image]

Comment: Please attach your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have both elements inside a div you can simply use flexbox to align them.

PS: you should provide us with some code in order to make your question more clear.

Take a look at [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to understand more how flexbox works.

Your code should look something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img />
    <p>Something...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, one simple way would be to put both elements inside a div container and apply the following styles.

```
.elements-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-start;
 }
```

Note that you can adjust the justify content,see [this link from css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information, as well as add a width attribute to the container as per your needs. Hope this helped in some way.